# s:select struts2 tag issue

Tags: java, html, struts2, struts

I have users inside an `ArrayList` of `UserDetails`. `UserDetails` has 2 fields: `id` and `name`.

I would like to have a Struts2 select tag which populates the user names, but on the click of submit button it should post the user `id`.

```
s:select list="users.userName" value="users.userId" size="0"
```

This is what i did..but it is not working for me.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the issue? Answer is in the question: use struts select tag

Comment: What have you tried? At least take a look at attributes that `<s:select>` tag takes.

Comment: I tried
<s:select list="users.userName" />
but it is not working for me

Comment: @AleksandrM:Good catch i hust read question in hurry :)

Comment: @AleksandrM can u tell me the way to do it?

Comment: @user1831612: Just take a look at `<s:select>` tag attributes http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/select.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like @AleksandrM said, check the [Document](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/select.html) here

It should look like this:

```
<s:select list="users" listKey="userName" listValue="userId"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:select list="UserDetails" listKey="name" listValue="id"/>
```